# Prevent django admin from escaping html

Tags: django, admin, escaping

I'm trying to display image thumbnails in django admin's list_display and I am doing it like this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'image',)
    list_display = ('title', '_get_thumbnail',)

    def _get_thumbnail(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(u'<img src="%s" />' % obj.admin_thumbnail.url)
```

Admin keeps displaying the thumbnail as escaped html, although I marked the string as safe. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As of Django 1.9, you can use [`format_html()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html), [`format_html_join()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html_join), or [`allow_tags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0) in your method. See the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) docs for more info.

The code in the question using `mark_safe` will work. However a better option for methods like these might be `format_html`, which will escape arguments.

```
def _get_thumbnail(self, obj):
    return format_html(u'<img src="{}" />', obj.admin_thumbnail.url)
```

In earlier versions of Django, using `mark_safe()` would not work, and Django would escape the output. The solution was to give the method an `allow_tags` attribute with the value set to True.

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'image',)
    list_display = ('title', '_get_thumbnail',)

    def _get_thumbnail(self, obj):
         return u'<img src="%s" />' % obj.admin_thumbnail.url
    _get_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Thanks you for clarification, I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: @Andy, if that works for you, click the check-mark under the score this answer has to accept it.

Comment: Not sure but I think that the right syntax is with `{}`, not `%s`. So it would be: `format_html(u'<img src="{}" />', obj.admin_thumbnail.url)`.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a rather late answer, but I thought a more complete implementation would be helpful to others...

If you don't have it already with django-filer, get easy_thumbnails `pip install easy-thumbnails`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.contrib import admin

from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer

from models import Photo


class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('_thumbnail', 'title', )
    list_display_links = ('_thumbnail', 'title', )  # This makes the icon clickable too
    readonly_fields = ('_thumbnail', )
    fields = ('title', 'photo', )

    def _thumbnail(self, obj):
        if obj.photo:
            thumbnailer = get_thumbnailer(obj.photo)
            thumb = thumbnailer.get_thumbnail({
                'crop': True,
                'size': (50, 50),
                # Sharpen it up a little, since its so small...
                'detail': True,
                # Put other options here...
            })
            # Note: we get the actual width/height rather than
            # hard-coding 50, 50, just to be DRYer
            return u'<img src="%s" alt="thumbnail: %s" width="%d" height="%d"/>' % (thumb.url, obj.photo.name, thumb.width, thumb.height)
        else:
            return "[No Image]"

    # Optional, Provide a nicer label in the display
    _thumbnail.short_description = 'Thumbnail'

    # Required, leaves the markup un-escaped
    _thumbnail.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```