# Django 1.4: return HTML in function

Tags: python, html, django, django-1.4

How can I return a HTML Tag, which will be interpreted, in a function in Django 1.4?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def my_link(self):
        return '<a href=google.com>google</a>'
```

Imagine I have this Model with the method my_link. In my Admin interface I want to display the columns `my_attribute` and `my_link`. But the problem is, that the html-Tag won't be interpreted. It just prints the text.

Since Django 1.5 there is the method `format_html()` in the module `django.utils.html`. But I need something similar in Django 1.4

**EDIT**
myapp.admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['my_attribute', 'my_link']

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `allow_tags` attribute:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def my_link(self):
        return '<a href=google.com>google</a>'
    my_link.allow_tags = True # <---
```

According to [`ModelAdmin.list_display` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> If the string given is a method of the model, ModelAdmin or a
>   callable, Django will HTML-escape the output by default. If you’d
>   rather not escape the output of the method, give the method an
>   allow_tags attribute whose value is True. However, to avoid an XSS
>   vulnerability, you should use format_html() to escape user-provided
>   inputs.

Comment: I tried this already. It doesn't work for me. Still the same behavior

Comment: thank you! I just found the same solution in this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298083/prevent-django-admin-from-escaping-html) post.