# Custom rendering of foreign field in form in django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my modelform I have a foreign key, I cannot figure out how to change the appearance of this field in template. I can change the text by changing

```
__unicode__
```

of the model, but how would I make it bold, for example?

in **models.py** I tried the following but form renders with  and all other tags as if they were just text:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    u'<b>Name</b>: {}\n<b>Loyal</b>: {}'.format(self.name, self.loyal)
```

my **template.html**:

```
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.client|safe}} 
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="btn btn-s btn-success">
  </form>
```

doesn't work.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.9 has a `format_html` function that might be what you are looking for. From [the Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html):

> `format_html(format_string, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> This is similar to str.format(), except that **it is appropriate for building up HTML fragments**. All args and kwargs are passed through conditional_escape() before being passed to str.format().
>
> **For the case of building up small HTML fragments, this function is to be preferred over string interpolation** using % or str.format() directly, because it applies escaping to all arguments - just like the template system applies escaping by default.

More information here: [Prevent django admin from escaping html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298083/prevent-django-admin-from-escaping-html)