# Django Admin override displayed field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have following model:

```
class Model(models.Model):

    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='com_creator',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60,default="")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000,default=" ")
    subtype = models.CharField(_("SubType"),max_length=100)
    typ = models.CharField(_("Type"),max_length=50)
    plus = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='com_plus', verbose_name=_('Plus'), blank=True)
    is_anonymous = models.BooleanField(_('Stay Anonymous'), blank=True, default=False)
```

The values in typ and subtype are codes, like: "6_0_p", (because the original values are ridiculosly long, so I use codes and a dict to translate to human readable form).

QUESTION: How can I intercept these values in django admin and translate them to human readable form?

This is what i tried so far:

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Model
    extra = 1
    exclude = ("username","creator","plus" ) 
    readonly_fields = ('subtype','typ','is_anonymous','created')
    fields = ('body','subtype','typ')

    def typ(self, obj):
        self.typ = "ppp"
        obj.typ = "ppp"
        return "pppp"
```

I tried returning the object, self, some other value. I also tried to set the value without using a callable just declaring "typ='xxx'". Nothing. I probably don't understand how this whole thing works ...

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a `readonly_field` which corresponds to your method name, then return anything from that method.

Documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('my_custom_field',)

    def my_custom_field(self, obj):
        return 'Return Anything Here'
```

Comment: I do have this approach in my example code. It's not doing it.

Comment: @stefan it won't work if you have a database field named the same. Name the method something other than your existing field, and put that in readonly_fields. Paste the above example and see it work. Add `my_custom_field` to the end of your `readonly_fields`, and add a method named the same to see it in action.

Comment: Great clarification @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita  - now how to I make the returned value a HTML? I want to display a list.

Comment: @Elendurwen see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298083/prevent-django-admin-from-escaping-html -- depends on version.

Answer (score 5):

I think that your code doesn't work because the **method** name is the same as the field.

You have to change the name of field, like _typ in fields tuple, then add a method called _typ that return anything or some obj attr.

i.e:

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Model
    extra = 1
    exclude = ("username","creator","plus" ) 
    readonly_fields = ('subtype','typ','is_anonymous','created')
    fields = ('body','subtype','_typ')

    def _typ(self, obj):
        return "pppp"
```

Comment: It says now: "FieldError: Unknown field(s)"

Comment: Yuji below explained to me in more detail. Your answer is technically also correct, but I understood it from hys effort. Many thanks to you as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Django 4 and above you can add a custom (readonly) field easily, like this:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdminAbstractAdmin):
    readonly_fields = [
        '_dynamic_field',
    ]
    fieldsets = [
        ('Form', {
            'fields': (
                '_dynamic_field',
            ),
            'classes': ('form-group',)
        }),
    ]

    def _dynamic_field(self, obj=None):
        if obj is not None:
            return 'Bar'
        return "Foo"

    # to change the label
    _dynamic_field.__name__ = "Dynamic field label"
```

How you can see, the field needs to be in `readonly_fields` and `fieldsets` too.

Answer (score 0):

`choices` allow this. They are https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#choices:

> A mapping or iterable in the format described below to use as choices for this field. If choices are given, they’re enforced by model validation and the default form widget will be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field.
>
> If a mapping [or iterable] is given, the key [or first element] is the actual value to be set on the model, and the [value or] second element is the human readable name.

Adapting https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types to your question:

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    class MyTypes(models.TextChoices):
        T6_0_P = '6_0_p', 'original value that is ridiculously long'
        T6_0_Q = '6_0_q', 'other original value that is ridiculously long'
        T7_0_P = '7_0_p', 'yet another original value that is ridiculously long'

    class MySubTypes(models.TextChoices):
        ST6_0_P = 's6_0_p', 'original value that is ridiculously long'
        ST6_0_Q = 's6_0_q', 'other original value that is ridiculously long'
        ST7_0_P = 's7_0_p', 'yet another original value that is ridiculously long'

    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='com_creator',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000, default=" ")
    subtype = models.CharField(_("SubType"), choices=MySubTypes, max_length=100)
    typ = models.CharField(_("Type"), choices=MyTypes, max_length=50)
    plus = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,related_name='com_plus', verbose_name=_('Plus'), blank=True
    )
    is_anonymous = models.BooleanField(_('Stay Anonymous'), blank=True, default=False)
```